# Overlapping Bar Chart using Chart.js

Tags: charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I want to develop a bar chart as shown below is it possible to develop it using chart.js?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible, see examples in this thread on Github https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5224. Notice the comment relating to offset, which will apply to versions of Chart js > 2.4.