# Horizontal overlapping of bars, not whole graph

Tags: chart.js

[image: Bar chart with overlapping bars]

I have been asked to create a bar graph similar to the above and I want to know if it is possible within chart.js?? I have had a look at a number of sites (such as [Overlapping Bar Chart using Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271197/overlapping-bar-chart-using-chart-js) and https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5224) but the idea there is to have two graphs behind each other directly - I need to be able to set the position of the blocks (i.e. almost go something like `margin-left:-5px` as I would in CSS) - or at least have some overlap (or about 40% overlap). If not I might have to build it in CSS but it would be great to use Chart JS.

Comment: I'm confused about the title of your post and the image you added to it. The title mentions a horizontal bar chart but the image shows a vertical bar chart. Can you please clarify?

Comment: But the bars are overlapping horizontally - yes it is a vertical graph though

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterUpdate` hook to shift the bars of individual datasets by the desired number of pixels as follows:

```
afterUpdate: function(chart) {
  let datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;
  for (let iDs = 1; iDs < datasets.length; iDs++) {
    let dataset = datasets[iDs];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset._meta[0].data.length; i++) {
      let model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model;
      model.x += iDs * offset;
      model.controlPointNextX += iDs * offset;
      model.controlPointPreviousX += iDs * offset;
    }
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet and see how it works.

```js
const offset = 12;

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterUpdate: function(chart) {
      let datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;
      for (let iDs = 1; iDs < datasets.length; iDs++) {
        let dataset = datasets[iDs];
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset._meta[0].data.length; i++) {
          let model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model;
          model.x += iDs * offset;
          model.controlPointNextX += iDs * offset;
          model.controlPointPreviousX += iDs * offset;
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["A"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'X',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [5],
        xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
        barThickness: 30,
      },
      {
        label: 'Y',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        data: [10],
        xAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
        barThickness: 30,
      },
      {
        label: 'Z',
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
        data: [15],
        xAxisID: "bar-x-axis3",
        barThickness: 30,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          id: "bar-x-axis3",
          display: false
        },
        {
          id: "bar-x-axis2",
          offset: true,
          display: false
        },
        {
          id: "bar-x-axis1",
          offset: true,
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        id: "bar-y-axis1",
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="150"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE**

Please also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025550/2358409) that provides a slightly improved solution.

Comment: Thank you for this - great answer! It works as expected however I have 2 graphs on the same page and I get an error `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. I know both graphs work independently but when put together it seems to error?

Comment: @Anthony: Please post a new question for this new issue, possibly with a code sample that reproduces the described error. This will make it much easier to come up with a solutions to this problem.

Comment: I have created the following js fiddle. I'm not sure it requires a new question though?? https://jsfiddle.net/ycpj7g8w/